# How to specify the Date format in r?

Tags: r

I had problem in specifying the date format of my data arranged as:

```
Date    Longitude   Latitude    Elevation   Max Temperature Min Temperature Precipitation   Wind    Relative Humidity   Solar
1/1/1979    40.625  10.1473999  594 31.784  14.711  0   1.34012963  0.332977248 23.69273112
1/2/1979    40.625  10.1473999  594 30.548  15.001  0   1.440527678 0.445704584 23.2192062
1/3/1979    40.625  10.1473999  594 30.029  18.724  0.020599366 1.950813349 0.532062642 18.34447248
1/4/1979    40.625  10.1473999  594 31.311  17.802  0   2.150911946 0.466495869 23.07077748
```

i tried using as.Date but the result is as follows:

```
gewane_t$Date <- as.Date(gewane_t$Date,format("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

> Error in charToDate(x) :
> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

any solution.

kind regards,

Comment: Instead of `as.Date(gewane_t$Date, format("%m/%d/%Y")` try `as.Date(gewane_t$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")`.

Comment: This is the outcome. Any suggestions.gewane_t$Date <- as.Date(gewane_t$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
Error in as.Date.numeric(gewane_t$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y") : 
  'origin' must be supplied

Comment: That's a strange message. This would suggest that `gewane_t$Date` is numerical. From the table above and your error message I would suggest it is a character string. Was this file open in Excel and saved? Excel shows a date, but in the background it is just a number.

Comment: yes it was saved in excel.

Comment: Ah ok, if the column was in date format and you save it as a `csv` file then it will be saved as a number (i.e. number of days as of 01-01-1900 on Windows machine and 01-01-1904 on Mac machine). You can try:  `as.Date(gewane_t$Date, origin = "1900-01-01")`

Answer (score 1):

Use `lubridate` `dmy` function.
This function automatically returns objects of class POSIXct and will work with either factors or characters.

Assuming your dataframe is called `gewane_t`
update of code `dmy` to `mdy`

```
library(lubridate)
gewane_t$Date <- mdy(gewane_t$Date)
```

Output:

```
  Date       Longitude Latitude Elevation   Max Temperature    Min Temperature_1 Precipitation  Wind
  <date>         <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>
1 1979-01-01      40.6     10.1       594  31.8        14.7 0               1.34         0.333  23.7
2 1979-02-01      40.6     10.1       594  30.5        15.0 0               1.44         0.446  23.2
3 1979-03-01      40.6     10.1       594  30.0        18.7 0.0206          1.95         0.532  18.3
4 1979-04-01      40.6     10.1       594  31.3        17.8 0               2.15         0.466  23.1
```

Comment: This result came:                                                                                                                 gewane_t$Date <- mdy(gewane_t$Date)
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: Ok I will check

Comment: I have checked. Have you installed `lubridate`. `install.packages("lubridate")`? Is the name of your dataframe `gewane_t` then it should work. Please let me know.

Comment: It is the same result.                                                                                                            > setwd("C:/Users/c/OneDrive/Desktop/Hydroclimatology/CFSR data for Hydroclimatology/for Gewane")
> gewanet <- read.csv("weatherdata-101406.csv",TRUE,",")
> class(gewanet)
[1] "data.frame"
> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    date, intersect, setdiff, union

> gewanet$Date <- mdy(gewanet$Date)
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: Is it because my data format is in mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: OK. I have edited the answer! And pay attention `gewane_t` is not `gewanet`

Comment: It didn't work with that either. But, i just selected the three columns that i needed (Date, Max. Temperature and Min. Tempeature) and saved it as new csv file. Then the as.Date(gewanet$Date, format("%m/%d/%Y") format worked. I don't know why.

Comment: make sure you use the right lubridate format mdy, dmy, etc are picky. Thus, when your date is in mm/dd/yyy then use mdy(), for dd/mm/yyyy obviously dmy()